# how to handle sinon.stub().throws() in unit test by Sinon JS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, chai

Am trying to invoke `fail` condition in my snippet.
But when I use `sinon.stub().throws()` method It shows me error.
Am unable to handle it in code.
**Here is my snippet:**

```
login() {
    let loginData = this.loginData;
    return this.authService.login(loginData).then(userData => {

      let msg = `${this.niceToSeeYouAgain} ${userData.email}!`;
      this.userAlertsService.showSuccessToast(msg);
      this.navigationService.afterLoggedIn();

      //above lines are covered in test cases

    }, errorInfo => {
      // below line are needed to test
      this.userAlertsService.showAlertToast(errorInfo);
    });
}
```

**And here is my unit-test snippet: **

```
it('.login() - should throw exception - in failure case', sinon.test(() => {

    let errorInfo = "some error";

    let stub = sinon.stub(authService, 'login').throws();

    let spy1 = sinon.spy(controller.userAlertsService, 'showAlertToast');


    //call function
    controller.login();
    // $timeout.flush();

    // expect things
    console.log(stub.callCount, stub.args[0]);

  }));
```

Please let me know what am doing wrong

Answer (score 15):

You need to wrap the function that you know is going to fail, and then `call` it. e.g.

```
 it('handles errors in methodThatCallsAnotherFailingMethod', function() {
      error = new Error("some fake error");
      sandbox.stub(SomeObject, "doSomething").throws(error);

      call = function() {
        // methodThatCallsAnotherFailingMethod calls SomeObject.doSomething()
        methodThatCallsAnotherFailingMethod();
      };

      expect(call).to.throw(Error);
});
```

When testing (or spying on) other stuff in `methodThatCallsAnotherFailingMethod` you can do this in your test:

```
  try {
    call();
   } catch (error) {
    expect(MySpy).to.have.been.calledWith(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a month old as of this answer, but I encountered a similar error, and Google hasn't yielded any explanation for this behavior. I wanted to test the failure branch of my login as well, and `stub.throws()` actually *threw* the error (causing the test to fail) instead of rejecting the login promise. If anyone knows why this happens, I'd appreciate it.

In any case, this is what worked for me:

```
let d = Q.defer();          // Or whichever promise library you use
d.reject();                 // Force the promise to fail
let stub = sinon.stub(authService, 'login').returns(d.promise);    // Should do what you want
// The rest of the test
```

Comment: Had a similar issue with throws and Promises on a mock.I'm assuming the API is the same.  Try using `rejects` instead of `throws` from the stub.